# Get Value from textview in edittext in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview

I'm just a beginner in Android development.I'm working on an application where I have to retrieve a textview that consists of characters and integers. I want to retrieve only Integers in my Edittext from that textview.

Text that I want to retrieve for Edittext

```
               <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="118dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
                android:text="Sun Glasses \n    Rs.729"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Edittext is here:

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextAmount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center" />
```

My attempt to achieve that:

```
private EditText editTextAmount;
private String paymentAmount;

private String paymentAmount;

editTextAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount);
amount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

editTextAmount.setText(amount.getText().toString());
paymentAmount = editTextAmount.getText().toString();
```

I tried everything and also followed many tutorials but not getting my desired result.
Hope I'll get help from you guys and I will appreciate your help.

Comment: why multiple `paymentAmount` ??

Comment: Please explain exactly what you want.

Comment: @AhmadAghazadeh he wants his `EditText` to only get the `729` part of the `TextView`'s text. But OP, you didn't really try everything, since you actually tried nothing but copypasting the textview's exact text.

Comment: the text in `textView ` is a string no matter if it contains numbers. you can use `subString` to get the numbers from the text.

Comment: @AhmadAghazadeh, I want that price money to be in edittext and there are characters and integers, so I'm not getting exactly and when I used that mentioned code, it changes nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I just have to change the input type of my edittext.

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextAmount"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this Way

```
    String amount = amount.getText().toString();
String getNum = ExtractNumberFromString(amount);
paymentAmount.setText(getNum);

    public static String ExtractNumberFromString(String cnvrtdDate){
        String [] dateArray = cnvrtdDate.split("|");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<dateArray.length;i++)
        {
            boolean ItIs = isNumeric(dateArray[i]);
            if(ItIs)
            {

                sb.append(dateArray[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                sb1.append(dateArray[i]);
            }
        }

    System.out.println("Numbers="+sb);
    System.out.println("Characters="+sb1);
        return  sb.toString();
    }


        public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
        {
            try
            {
                int d = Integer.parseInt(str);
            }
            catch(Exception nfe)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    String regex = "[0-9]+";
    String data = amount.getText().toString();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(data);
    String text="";
    while (m.find()) {
        text+=","+m.group();
    }
    editTextAmount.setText(amount.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the string from edit text and then use a regular expression to extract the numbers from the string. Something like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(editTextAmount.getText().toString());
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

this would print all the numbers in the edit text.

the "-?" allows it to capture negative numbers as well. You can remove that since i doubt amount will be negative.